# How to pick only every 2nd and 4th value of a line using while(!feof)?

Tags: javascript, php

I am importing a .txt file using the while(!feof function.
It works fine.

But now I need to only import the 2nd and 4th position/value of each line.

How can that be done?

Below you can see the code I am currently using. That code imports the whole file - line by line.

```
$txtimport = fopen("MyFile.txt", "r") or die("I died");
// Output one line until end-of-file
echo '<div id="someID" style="display: block">';
while(!feof($txtimport)) {
echo '<ar>'.fgets($txtimport).'</ar><br />';
}
echo '</div>';
fclose($txtimport);
```

**The .txt file looks like this:**

1;Hello;World;How;Are;You?
A;I;am;fine;thank;you
Good;to;hear;from;you;again

**Expected output**

Hello How
I fine
to from

Notice
The .txt. file follows the same logic for each line. Each line consists of 6 positions splitted by ";"

*Logic*
sometekst1;sometekst2;sometekst3;sometekst4;sometekst5;sometekst6

Comment: Don't know about javascript or php but, [in C, `while(!feof())` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong?r=SearchResults) (question was originally tagged with "c").

Comment: @pmg it is equally wrong in PHP. And considered "best practice" :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode()`:

```
$txtimport = fopen("MyFile.txt", "r") or die("I died");

echo '<div id="someID" style="display: block">';
while (($line = fgets($txtimport)) !== false) {
    $parts = explode(";", $line);
    echo "<span>$parts[1]</span><span>$parts[3]</span><br/>";
}
echo '</div>';
fclose($txtimport);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) but with a delimiter of `;` (the third parameter) will allow you to read the file directly as a series of fields and then output the individual items...

```
$txtimport = fopen("MyFile.txt", "r") or die("I died");
// Output one line until end-of-file
echo '<div id="someID" style="display: block">';
while($data = fgetcsv($txtimport, null, ";" )) {
    echo '<ar>'.$data[1]." ".$data[3].'</ar><br />';
}
echo '</div>';
fclose($txtimport);
```